# How %0|%0 works?

Tags: loops, batch-file

I’ve seen a post of how `%0|%0`, but I’m still not very sure, is it a loop to loop it self or to open another file to run it again and delete it self?

Can it be looped in a batch file? I cannot use my pc right now to experiment.

Comment: It is the script path and name.

Comment: @Squashman `%0` yes, but `%0|%0` will cause a fork bomb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say: *"I cannot use my pc right now to experiment"*.

Are you sure it is not: *"I experiment with this, so I cannot use my pc right now"*. `:)`

Jokes aside, `%0|%0` is pretty much a type of fork bomb.

`|` pipe takes the output of the first command and sends it to the next command after the pipe.

In this case of `%0|%0` you are piping the batch-file to itself, creating a permanent recursive loop that will consume resources quickly and eventually crash your system.

to try illustrate what happens here.

let's say the batch file is `dummy.cmd` the `%0|%0` will look like this:

```
D:\dummy.cmd | d:\dummy.cmd
```

launching this will start a loop where it launches itself repeatedly, similar to:

```
                                         dummy.cmd ..etc..             
                          dummy.cmd ->   dummy.cmd ..etc..       
             dummy.cmd ->
                                         dummy.cmd ..etc..
                          dummy.cmd ->   dummy.cmd ..etc..
dummy.cmd -> 
                          dummy.cmd ->   dummy.cmd ..etc..
             dummy.cmd ->                dummy.cmd ..etc..
          
                          dummy.cmd ->   dummy.cmd ..etc..
                                         dummy.cmd ..etc..
```

but what you need to understand is that it is not just the one process spawning another in a loop, each spawned process repeats itself again..
So the first process creates two more, these 2 each creates two more, these four creates two each, etc.

Each of the pipe actions forks to a `cmd` process internal to the initial process window.

So if you were lucky enough to run a `tasklist` while this is running, you will see the mess created in the background with the speed `cmd` processes are initiated.

See [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb#:%7E:text=In%20computing%2C%20a%20fork%20bomb,system%20due%20to%20resource%20starvation.) as well.